# Local file not in sync with master, but still says All up to date

Tags: git

I am working on a project, on an old branch called mono4. When I do a `git pull origin master`,

I get the message:

```
* branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
```

So as you see, it says that my local branch is up to date with master. 
But my problem is, that one of my files (so far, I have only seen 1 file) not up to date with the master. For example, locally I have a JS function that gives an error when running my application, saying that there is some variable that is undefined. Looking at the same file, but on the remote master, it is true that the 2 files are different.

I have not experienced this before. What can cause this, and what can I do to make git to actually stop saying that my branch is up to date with the master, and pull the latest version?

Comment: Output from `git log --oneline --decorate -all` ( perhaps truncated if long ) and `git status` would be extremely helpful in helping you :)

Comment: To add to @RandomSort's comment, it's even better to use `git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph`. Remember this as "get help from A DOG: All Decorate Oneline Graph". The key to understanding why Git thinks your branch is "up to date" is in the *graph* part of this.

Answer (score 1):

You pull master but you work on branch called mono4 so make it up to date too:

```
git fetch origin mono4
git pull origin mono4
```

Comment: I did try this too, but it also says that mono4 is up to date. This is true since I pushed to mono4 before pull from master

Answer (score 1):

`Already up-to-date` means that `mono4` in the local repository has merged/included all the commits of `master` in the remote repository. Now `mono4` should be ahead of `master` by some commits.

There was once a merge before your pull. It was a true merge and there could be conflicts during the merge. It's possible that the file on `mono4` is different from the one on `master` after the conflicts were resolved. It's also possible that new commits have been made on `mono4` since that merge, no matter it was a true merge or a fast-forward merge. You could run `git log mono4 -- file` and `git log FETCH_HEAD -- file` to see what happened to the file on both branches.

As to the error, modify the file and commit the changes on `mono4` to fix it.

Comment: Yes, that is true. When I did a git pull at first, I had several conflicts from different files, which I had to merge manually. I did the merge, commited and pushed to the mono branch. After that, it says that I am up to date with master

Comment: If Branch A merges Branch B, then A is up-to-date with B. It doesn't mean that a file of A now has the same content with the one of B. A has applied all the changes from B, but some of the changes may be adjusted during the merge.

Comment: This confuses me a bit. Isn't the point of git pull and merge to make files on your working branch, to have same content as those on the branch you are pulling from?

Comment: @MOR_SNOW No.  If so, why don't we simply use `master`? A merge introduces changes, not to copy their contents and overwrite ours.